# Why is Coffeescript of the opinion that shadowing is a bad idea

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I've wanted to switch to Coffeescript for a while now and yesterday I thought I'm finally sold but then I stumbled across [Armin Ronachers article](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/12/22/implicit-scoping-in-coffeescript/) on shadowing in Coffeescript.

Coffeescript indeed now abandoned shadowing, an example of that problem would be if you use the same iterator for nested loops.

```
var arr, hab, i;

arr = [[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  var subArr = arr[i];
  (function(){
      for(var i = 0; i < subArr.length; i++){
        console.log(subArr[i]);
      }
  })();
}
```

Because cs only declares variables once I wouldn't be able to do this within coffeescript

Shadowing has been intentionally removed and I'd like to understand why the cs-authors would want to get rid of such a feature?

**Update**: Here is a [better example](https://gist.github.com/Kallikanzarid/4736201) of why Shadowing is important, derived from an issue regarding this problem [on github](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2697)

PS: I'm not looking for an answer that tells me that I can just insert plain Javascript with backticks.

Comment: Is it a feature? Something that makes programmers confused or more error-prone should be always avoided. No?

Comment: without explicit declaration, how is the interpreter supposed to know whether your two `i` variables are supposed to be the same one or not?

Comment: @Alnitak that's exactly my point, before in cs you could shadow a variable by doing `while i := 0`

Comment: Even more confusing is that this absence of shadowing isn't even consistent. If you have several files, variables will be shadowed by file (unless explicitly set to the global scope). there is this case where function parameters are shadowing other variables, but using another variable inside this very function is not shadowing any other variable of the same name.

Overall, CoffeeScript is against shadowing because they have no idea what they're doing. When Ashkenas states that it's "a huge conceptual simplification", I hear "It's too hard to implement right".

Comment: @Floby shadowing was in coffeescript until recently. For reasons I cannot fathom they took it out. Hence my question. Ashkenaz seems like a smart guy so I'm hoping there is a really good reason for it.

Comment: I'm not really a coffeescript user myself as you surely noticed. I have no idea why they took it out, but my guess is that it wasn't really thought through

Comment: Despite working with over 50,000 lines of coffeescript, I've never been bitten by the problem you're describing.  I would suggest that if this is causing issues, then it's indicative of deeper architectural problems.

Comment: @AaronDufour reassuring! Now that I know a little more about CoffeeScript it seems like shadowing isn't really that necessary, with do for example.

Comment: @kjo, in hindsight, I've been using coffeescript for a while now and it hasn't bothered me at all. I'd encourage anyone to give it a go, it's nice to read and some of it's features are great, like having a class system built in is great!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you read the discussion on [this ticket](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/712), you can see Jeremy Ashkenas, the creator of CoffeeScript, explaining some of the reasoning between forbidding explicit shadowing:

> We all know that dynamic scope is bad, compared to lexical scope, because it makes it difficult to reason about the value of your variables. With dynamic scope, you can't determine the value of a variable by reading the surrounding source code, because the value depends entirely on the environment at the time the function is called. If variable shadowing is allowed and encouraged, you can't determine the value of a variable without tracking backwards in the source to the closest var variable, because the exact same identifier for a local variable can have completely different values in adjacent scopes. In all cases, when you want to shadow a variable, you can accomplish the same thing by simply choosing a more appropriate name. It's much easier to reason about your code if a local variable name has a single value within the entire lexical scope, and shadowing is forbidden.
>
> So it's a very deliberate choice for CoffeeScript to kill two birds with one stone -- simplifying the language by removing the "var" concept, and forbidding shadowed variables as the natural consequence.

If you search "scope" or "shadowing" in the CoffeeScript issues, you can see that this comes up all the time. I will not opine here, but the gist is that the CoffeeScript Creators believe it leads to simpler code that is less error-prone.

Okay, I will opine for a little bit: shadowing doesn't matter. You can come up with contrived examples that show why either approach is better. The fact is that, with shadowing or not, you need to search "up" the scope chain to understand the life of a variable. If you explicitly declare your variables ala JavaScript, you might be able to short-circuit sooner. But it doesn't matter. If you're ever unsure of what variables are in scope in a given function, you're doing it wrong.

Shadowing *is* possible in CoffeeScript, without including JavaScript. If you ever *actually* need a variable that you know is locally scoped, you can get it:

```
x = 15
do (x = 10) ->
  console.log x
console.log x
```

So on the off-chance that this comes up in practice, there's a fairly simple workaround.

Personally, I prefer the explicitly-declare-every-variable approach, and will offer the following as my "argument":

```
doSomething = ->
  ...
  someCallback = ->
    ...
      whatever = ->
        ...
        x = 10
        ...
```

This works great. Then all of a sudden an intern comes along and adds this line:

```
x = 20
doSomething = ->
  ...
  someCallback = ->
    ...
      whatever = ->
        ...
        x = 10
        ...
```

And bam, the code is broken, but the breakage doesn't show up until way later. Whoops! With `var`, that wouldn't have happened. But with "usually implicit scoping unless you specify otherwise", it would have. So. Anyway.

I work at a company that uses CoffeeScript on the client and server, and I have *never* heard of this happening in practice. I think the amount of time saved in not having to type the word `var` everywhere is greater than the amount of time lost to scoping bugs (that never come up).

## Edit:

Since writing this answer, I have seen this bug happen two times in actual code. Each time it's happened, it's been extremely annoying and difficult to debug. My feelings have changed to think that CoffeeScript's choice is bad times all around.

Some CoffeeScript-like JS alternatives, such as LiveScript and coco, use two different assignment operators for this: `=` to declare variables and `:=` to modify variables in outer scopes. This seems like a more-complicated solution than just preserving the `var` keyword, and something that also won't hold up well once `let` is widely usable.

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes I'm amazed at the quality of answers you can get on SO.

Answer (score 7):

The main issue here isn't shadowing, its CoffeeScript conflating variable initialization and variable reassignment and not allowing the programmer to specify their intent exactly

When the coffee-script compiler sees `x = 1`, it has no idea whether you meant

> *I want a new variable, but I forgot I'm already using that name in an upper scope*

or

> *I want to reassign a value to a variable I originally created at the top of my file*

This is not how you forbid shadowing in a language. This is how you make a language that punishes users who accidentally reuse a variable name with subtle and hard to detect bugs.

CoffeeScript could've been designed to forbid shadowing but keep declaration and assignment separate by keeping `var`. The compiler would simply complain about this code:

```
var x = blah()

var test = -> 
  var x = 0
```

with "Variable x already exists (line 4)"

but it would also complain about this code:

```
x = blah()

test = ->
  x = 0;
```

with "Variable x doesn't exist (line 1)"

However, since `var` was removed, the compiler has no idea whether you meant meant "declare" or "reassign" and can't help.

Using the same syntax for two different things is not "simpler", even though it may look like it is. I recommend [Rich Hickey's talk, Simple made easy](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Simple-Made-Easy) where he goes in depth why this is so.

Comment: Most of the debate over this issue has amounted to restatements of preference differences. This answer constitutes actual progress in the discussion. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> Because cs only declares variables once the loop will not work as intended.

What is the intended way for those loops to work? The condition in `while i = 0 < arr.length` will always be true if the `arr` is not empty, so it will be an infinite loop. Even if it's only one `while` loop that won't work as intended (assuming infinite loops are not what you're looking for):

```
# This is an infinite loop; don't run it.
while i = 0 < arr.length
  console.log arr[i]
  i++
```

The correct way of iterating arrays sequentially is using the `for ... in` construct:

```
arr = [[1,2], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]]

for hab in arr
  # IDK what "hab" means.
  for habElement in hab
    console.log habElement
```

I know that this answer sound like going off on a tangent; that the main point is why CS discourages variable shadowing. But if examples are to be used to argument in favour of or against something, the examples ought to be good. This example doesn't help the idea that variable shadowing should be encouraged.

### Update (actual answer)

About the variable shadowing issue, one thing that it worth clarifying is that the discussion is about whether variable shadowing should be allowed between different *function* scopes, not blocks. Within the same function scope, variables will hoist the whole scope, no matter where they are first assigned; this semantic is inherited from JS:

```
->
  console.log a # No ReferenceError is thrown, as "a" exists in this scope.
  a = 5

->
  if someCondition()
    a = something()
  console.log a # "a" will refer to the same variable as above, as the if 
                # statement does not introduce a new scope.
```

The question that is sometimes asked is why not adding a way to explicitly declare the scope of a variable, like a `let` keyword (thus shadowing other variables with the same name in enclosing scopes), or make `=` always introduce a new variable in that scope, and have something like `:=` to assign variables from enclosing scopes without declaring one in the current scope. The motivation for this would be to avoid this kind of errors:

```
user = ... # The current user of the application; very important!

# ...
# Many lines after that...
# ...

notifyUsers = (users) ->
  for user in users # HO NO! The current user gets overridden by this loop that has nothing to do with it!
    user.notify something
```

CoffeeScript's argument for not having a special syntax for shadowing variables is that you simply shouldn't do this kind of thing. Name your variables clearly. Because even if shadowing would be allowed it would be very confusing to have two variables with two different meanings with the same name, one in an inner scope and one in an enclosing scope.

Use adequate variable names according to how much context you have: if you have little context, e.g. a top-level variable, you'll probably need a very specific name to describe it, like `currentGameState` (*especially* if it's not a constant and its value will change with time); if you have more context, you can get away with using less descriptive names (because the context is already there), like loop variables: `killedEnemies.forEach (e) -> e.die()`.

If you want to know more about this design decision, you may be interested in reading Jeremy Ashkenas opinions in these HackerNews threads: [link](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4535885), [link](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2864728); or in the many CoffeeScript issues where this topic is discussed: [#1121](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1121), [#2697](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2697) and others.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, my example was wrong, I used [this](http://js2coffee.org/) to convert my javascript and hadn't properly checked the output. I've updated the example, however, your answer doesn't really answer my question, I think it should have been a comment really.

Comment: @nimrod, it was too long for a comment. Your new example still doesn't work: even though `var i` appears once for each of those JS `for` loops, there's only one variable `i` (that will be shared among the two loops), because variables in JS have function scope. You can try it [here]: it will only print the first sub-array. Besides, providing a valid answer is difficult if the question itself is invalid; now that you've updated your question maybe i can update my answer :D

Comment: I'm being silly, updated it again, it'll work as intended now :)

Comment: Cool; i updated my answer too. I hope it now does better to answer your question. Also, you may be interested in the the `do` keyword, that can effectively create a new function scope if you need it (very useful for loops that create function that will be executed later).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very comprehensive!

Comment: You know that you can do ` var user ` in CoffeeScript, right?