# Closures over not yet defined variables in CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript, closures

For the following code:

```
inc = -> value = (value ? 0) + 1
dec = -> value = (value ? 0) - 1
print = -> console.log value ? 0
```

How can you make this work properly, so `inc` and `dec` close upon `value` instead of creating separate function-local variables, **in the way other than explicitly assigning something to `value`**?

In plain Javascript, you would just declare `var value` at outer scope:

```
var value;

function inc() { value = (value || 0) + 1; };
function dec() { value = (value || 0) - 1; };
function print() { console.log(value || 0); };
```

What is CoffeeScript way for exactly the same thing?

Comment: Same way, just declare `value = null` above. But why would you introduce mutation like this instead of passing parameters to your functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CoffeeScript, *the* way to *introduce a local variable* is to *assign* to the variable in the appropriate scope.

This is simply the way that CoffeeScript was defined and as such is similar to Python or Ruby, which do not require a "variable declaration", except CoffeeScript also allows forward access. A side-effect is that [one cannot shadow a lexical variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223430/why-is-coffeescript-of-the-opinion-that-shadowing-is-a-bad-idea).

Just as with the placement of `var` in JavaScript, *where* this assignment is done (as long as it is in the correct scope) does not affect the scope of the variable.

Given

```
x = undefined
f = -> x
// JS
var f, x;
x = void 0;
f = function() {
  return x;
};
```

Given

```
f = -> x
x = undefined
// JS
var f, x;
f = function() {
  return x;
};
x = void 0;
```